# Insert data from asp.net to ms access database

Tags: sql, asp.net, ms-access

I am trying to create my own website and I do not have much experience. I have a problem to insert data to MS access. 
I am not too sure what is wrong with my code, somehow it is not working. 
Below it is my code:

```vb
    <%@ Page Language="VB" Debug="true" enableEventValidation="false" EnableViewStateMac="false"  %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.Oledb" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="System.Net.Mail" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %>




   <script runat="server">
   Dim LUsername As String
   Dim dpic As Image
   Dim MyCookieValue As String
   Dim objConn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("\easytourtravelagency.mdb"))
   Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
   Dim ds1 As New DataSet()
   Dim ds2 As New DataSet()


   Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

   Dim cmd124 As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO BookingDetails(CarID,Name,Innitial,EmailAddress,ContactNo,Gender,PickUpLocation,DateAndTime,NumberOfPassanger,SpecialRequest Values (@CarID, @Name, @EmailAddress, @ContactNo,@Gender,@PickUpLocation,@DateAndTime,@NumberOfPassanger,@SpecialRequest))", objConn)
    cmd124.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarID", CarID.Text)
    cmd124.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name.Text)
    cmd124.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", EmailAddress.Text)
    cmd124.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNo", ContactNo.Text)
    cmd124.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", Gender.Text)
    cmd124.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PickUpLocation", PickUpLocation.Text)
    cmd124.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAndTime", DateAndTime.Text)
    cmd124.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumberOfPassanger", NumberOfPassanger.Text)
    cmd124.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SpecialRequest", SpecialRequest.Text)
    cmd124.Connection.Open()
    cmd124.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd124.Connection.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I do not know ASP, your SQL has syntax errors as it is missing the closing parenthesis in `INSERT INTO` clause after listing columns and has an extra parenthesis after `VALUES` clause:

```sql
INSERT INTO BookingDetails(CarID,Name,Innitial,EmailAddress,
              ContactNo,Gender,PickUpLocation,DateAndTime,
              NumberOfPassanger,SpecialRequest              -- MISSING PARERNTHESIS
VALUES (@CarID, @Name, @EmailAddress, @ContactNo,@Gender,@PickUpLocation,
        @DateAndTime,@NumberOfPassanger,@SpecialRequest))   -- EXTRA PARENTHESIS
```

Comment: Hi.. Thanks a lot. it it due to my sql error. thanks.